# Converting dom to svg image and displaying it in pdf file

Tags: javascript, php, svg, mpdf, dom-to-image

I am using a dom-to-image library for converting an HTML table to an SVG image and displaying that image in the pdf file using MPDF library later on.

**HTML**
This table is an example

```
<table id="tableId"> 
<tr> 
  <td> 1row1column </td>
  <td> 1row2column </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td> 2row1column </td>
  <td> 2row2column </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**
Here I am using the dom-to-image library's toSvg function to convert the dom to SVG formatted image, sending the data URL to server-side with ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"></script>
   var node = document.getElementById('tableId');
            function filter (node) {
                return (node.tagName !== 'i');
            }
            domtoimage.toSvg(node).then(dataUrl => {
                domtoimage.toSvg(node, {
                    quality: 1.0,
                    bgcolor: "white",
                    filter: filter /* , width: "900px", */
                }).then(
                    dataUrl2 => {

                        // var link = document.createElement('a');
                        // link.download = 'actual.svg';
                        // link.href = dataUrl2;
                        // link.click();

                        $.ajax(
                            'download.php',
                            {
                                data: {
                                    image: dataUrl2,
                                    imageName:"textContainer.svg"
                                },
                                type: "POST",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    console.log(data.message);
                                },
                                error: function () {
                                    console.log(data.message);
                                    //  alert('There was some error performing the AJAX call!');
                                },
                                beforeSend: function () {
                                    //  alert('There was some error performing the AJAX call!');
                                },
                            }
                        );
                    }
                )
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
            });
```

**PHP**
I am getting the data URL(`$data`) and the imageName(`$imageName`) from `$_POST` global variable, removing everything before the `<svg>` tag and removing the `%0A` string which I had a problem with it in the beginning, putting the content to SVG file:

```
$data = $_POST['image'];
$imageName = $_POST['imageName'];
$svgData = str_replace('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,', '', $data);
$svgData = str_replace('%0A', '', $svgData);
file_put_contents("/tables/" . $imageName, $svgData);
```

The file is being downloaded and the SVG file is being displayed in Opera, Firefox, Microsoft Edge without any problem, but when it comes to adding this SVG file to pdf or to any other vector graphics editor like Inkscape the SVG image not working.

**The question:**
Can be done without using any library?
and If there is a library for doing this in the correct way, can we make the SVG works in pdf files too?

Comment: You've shown everything that is working but not what isn't. What is $svgData i.e. what is in the file /tables/$imageName? And what command are you using to convert it to pdf or to load it in Inkscape?

Comment: `$svgData` is the data URL which i am getting from `domtoimage.toSvg` function, nothing in the `$imgaeName` file, it is empty and I am filling it with the `svg` tag after removing the `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,` from data URL.

Comment: The data URL I am getting from domtoimage.toSvg function is here: 
[dataURL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rewan-95/dom-to-image-svg-problem/main/dataURL.txt)

Comment: What should I write in my $imageName file before adding the SVG content with `file_put_contents` ?

Comment: I have already shared the data URL @RobertLongson , [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rewan-95/dom-to-image-svg-problem/main/svgData.txt) you can find the content of `$svgData`
in more clear way, and the file which named $imageName is empty and will be dynamically created.

Comment: Inkscape [doesn't support foreignObject](https://alpha.inkscape.org/vectors/www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic9528.html?f=16&t=13086), I imagine whatever you're using for pdf conversion doesn't either.

Comment: My question :
Do you know any library to get rid of foreignObject without affecting the SVG file.

Comment: We don't do find me a library questions here I'm afraid.

Comment: Even you haven't suggested any solution to the problem yet. thank you for your time and effort :)